# How to count the number of rows in a database table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have database created by Django model, where `status` and `id` and `username` are the fields of the table `Messages`.

I need to count the number of rows where `status value= 0` for a particular `username`.

This is my incomplete code:

```
Message_me = Messages.objects.get(username='myname')
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Message_me = Messages.objects.filter(username='myname', status=0).count()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can either use Python's `len()` or use the `count()` method on any queryset depending on your requirements. Also note, using `len()` will evaluate the queryset so it's always feasible to use the provided `count()` method.

It can be used as follows:

```
message_count = models.Messages.objects.filter(username='username', status=0).count()
```

Alternatively, (if you do not worry about performance) you can also use `len()`:

```
message_count = len(models.Messages.objects.filter(username='username', status=0))
```

You should also go through the [QuerySet API Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for more information.

Comment: please provide the necessary imports with code excerpts

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of you can use the Model

```
// In models.py
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

// In views.py
from .models import A
def index(View):
    c = A.objects.filter(username='myname', status=0).count()
    print c // This will give you the count of the rows
```